# Auto Increment overlapping when inserting from different table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two different tables. They are both different. The problem I'm having is;

the tables increments give me an error when I try to insert one row into the other table. For example:

I have one table where it stores the information of a pending registered user. So if someone register lets say they were given the id of **24**. And in my other table i have around **56** members. How would I insert the pending member with the ID **24** into the members table without overlapping the ID's.

**Edit:**

Query's for adding it to pending registration:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT players SET user='$user', rank='$rank', date='$date', tag='$tag'", $db1)
```

or die(mysql_error());

Query for accepting the pending registration:

```
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 $result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO players SELECT * FROM pending WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 

 $result2= mysql_query("DELETE FROM pending WHERE id=$id")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to do something that is not very wise or there is a systematic problem in your architecture. Could you post an example of your sql queries?

Comment: Show your table schemas. But in essence you can have two absolutely independent auto_increment ids in both tables.

Comment: In your first query you have a syntax problem and more importantly insetting into a `player` table instead of `pending`. Where is the actual query that you use to insert a row into pending table?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with:

"INSERT INTO players SELECT * FROM pending WHERE id=$id"

You probably do not want to insert the pending id into the players table. The id column in the players table should be auto increment and should not be set explicitly.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html on how to make a auto increment column.